# VB.net SqlDataReader how to show messagebox if GetString function has null value?

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms

I have a login form which I need to check my database whether the user input of email and password matches the database.

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click


    myConn = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.MySQLData)

    myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand

    myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Email FROM dbo.[User]" &
                        " WHERE Email = '" & tbEmail.Text & "'"

    myConn.Open()
    myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader

    myReader.Read()


    If myReader.IsDBNull(0) Then

        MessageBox.Show("The email address input is invalid or does not exist in database.")

    ElseIf myReader.GetString(0) <> tbEmail.Text Then

        MessageBox.Show("The email address input is invalid or does not exist in database.")

    Else

        MessageBox.Show("Email address is OK")

    End If


    myReader.Close()
    myConn.Close()
```

This is only the email portion. I also have a password portion which I have yet to put in.

My code above does not work however. What is the best way to check against database for login?

Comment: Define "does not work".  In what *specific* way does it fail?  Also note that your code is wide open to SQL injection.  You should be using query parameters instead of directly executing user input as code.

Comment: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the HasRows property to avoid the requirement to call the Read method of the DataTableReader if there are no rows within the current result set.  - Msdn

```
     If reader.HasRows Then
       myReader.Read() 
     Else
       MessageBox.Show("no data present")
     End If
```

Comment: Password seems to be case insensitive however. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment above, the error is:

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

This means that the code *assumes* that at least one record is being returned by the SQL query, but *no records* are being returned.  That is, there is no record matching the `WHERE` clause conditions.

You should check for the existence of records before trying to read them.  When using a `SqlDataReader`, this is often done by examining the boolean result of the `Read()` method.  For example:

```
While myReader.Read()
    ' read the values here, for example:
    myReader.GetString(0)
End While
```

As soon as `myReader.Read()` evaluates to `False`, that means no more records are present in the query result.  If it evaluates to `False` on the first attempt, that means there are no records in the query result in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

From the youtube video shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyjGP4fP7IE

The code `myReader.HasRows` will check against the database with no hassle.

My new code:

myConn = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.MySQLData)

```
    myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand

    myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Email, Password FROM dbo.[User]" &
                        " WHERE Email = '" & tbEmail.Text & "'" &
                        " AND Password = '" & tbPassword.Text & "'"

    myConn.Open()
    myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader



    If myReader.HasRows Then
        LoginScreen.Show()

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email or Password")

    End If



    myReader.Close()
    myConn.Close()
```